# What is the correct product of the Diels-Alder reaction between 2-ethoxybuta-1,3-diene and (Z)-acrylaldehyde-3-d?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

What is the correct product of the Diels-Alder reaction between 2-ethoxybuta-1,3-diene and (Z)-acrylaldehyde-3-d?

It keeps mentioning that my regio-selectivity is incorrect. And that I should consider the charge distributions of the diene and dienophile to figure it out correctly, but I honestly have no idea.

[image: screenshot of What is the correct product of the Diels-Alder reaction between 2-ethoxybuta-1,3-diene and (Z)-acrylaldehyde-3-d?]

Comment: You're also likely to get the endo product over the exo product.

Answer (score 3):

These resonance structures and the polarization shown within explain the regioselectivity (1,4 isomer instead of 1,3) in the product.

[image]